# How to implicitly pass user from a request to corresponding serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a following code:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'content', 'owner')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'owner': {'write_only': True},
        }

class ArticleList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Article.objects.filter(owner=user.id)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['owner'] = self.request.user.id
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I have to explicitly pass user from request in `post` method of ArticleList ApiView to satisfy ForeignKey non-empty requirement. This is fine. But I have another models with a ForeignKey to `User` and as a result it leads to many copy-paste lines, especially in POST and PUT methods.
Does anybody knows more elegant DRY solution?